# Automatically/dynamically update TextView text in Android

Tags: android, textview, observer-pattern

I have an android app that I have decided to rewrite, one of the reasons for the rewrite is because I could have 10+ TextViews with text set based on a variable in a class e.g.:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.myNumber = 5;   // inside MyClass - public int myNumber;

LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

TextView myTextView = new TextView(getActivity());  //In a fragment
myTextView.setText(String.format("myNumber currently has a value of %d", myClass.myNumber));

mainLayout.addView(myTextView);
return view;
```

Up until now I have been using .setOnClickListener on the buttons/views that change myNumber, to set the text of the view again when the value of myNumber changes, which then calls .invalidate() to redraw the TextView, this has worked fine, but I use this method very heavily and code is getting quite repetitive and changing one integer can affect quite a lot of views (all of which use it differently - such as different wording, or a calculation (e.g. myNumber * 2)).  I guess it's because it's made an immutable string in the TextView.

I have tried to create a custom TextView that implements Observer (making MyClass extend Observable) and in the update method I can get it to invalidate itself for the refresh, but it still has the same text.  I have also tried creating single element arrays, in an attempt to pass the reference not the value in the hope that when it is changed and then the view is invalidated it will pick up the new value but the text still ends up remaining the same.

How can I get a TextView that will auto update when the value of myNumber has changed?  Some sort of binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bindroid](http://www.davidpoll.com/2013/03/17/bindroid-a-binding-framework-for-android/) works perfectly for this, just a note for users, using fragments the sample application is using `this` from an Activity so the bind method using Activity is called, so in the fragment I was using `getActivity()` which caused it to not work properly, digging around in the library I found a bind method that takes a View and passed in my `view` which gets inflated in the fragment and it works great!!!  This is super easy to integrate btw it was just me not getting it!